# Django get_object_or_404 or filter exists

Tags: python, django, filter

We need to identify the object is available in model or not.

There are two methods are available to check if exists ,

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists()
```

or

```
get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
```

Which query is better and efficient ?

Note: No need to perform any actions using that object(pk). Just want to know if exists or not ..

Comment: Well, do you want to raise an HTTP 404 if it doesn't exist or not?

Comment: @Ben Yes, if data not available should return Http404

Comment: The use `get_object_or_404` - that's what it's there for!

Comment: We have lot of datas, we want more efficient query.

Answer (score 16):

Using

```
get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
```

is a shortcut for

```
try:
    my_model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
except:
    raise Http404
```

Therefore you should only use `get_object_or_404` if you want to return a 404 error when the object doesn't exist.

If you don't actually need the model object, then in theory it would be more efficient to use `exists()` instead of `get()`, because `exists()` doesn't actually return the object:

```
if not MyModel.objects.exists():
    raise Http404
```

In practice, I'm not sure whether you would actually notice the difference. Therefore you might choose to use `get_object_or_404` to make the code slightly simpler.

Answer (score 8):

Using `exists` would be faster, but not that obvious. We can take a look at what those query do inside by logging the SQL queries:

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

User.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()
get_object_or_404(User, pk=1)

＃ (0.000) SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1; args=(1,)
＃ (0.001) SELECT "users"."id", "users"."password", ... FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1; args=(1,)
```

Then the answer is obvious now. They have almost the same queries, but `get_object_or_404` will get all the columns in a table while `exist` only take `one`. But this would never be a big deal.